# Joining Using LIKE operator in Neteeza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table like:
[image]

which I am joining to another table:
[image]

I want to get an output table that looks like this:
[image]

I have discovered that my version of Netezza doesn't support concat but supports || instead. I have tried joining the table using the LIKE operator as follows:

SELECT A.*, CASE WHEN A.GENERIC_NAME LIKE ('%'||B.O_DRUGS||'%') THEN B.DRUG_CLASS ELSE NULL END AS OTHER_DRUGS FROM DRUG1 AS A LEFT JOIN DRUG_LIST AS B ON A.GENERIC_NAME LIKE ('%'||O_DRUGS||'%');

The code works for exact matches but the fuzzy matching is still not working. Clearly, I'm not using the like operator correctly for this purpose.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LIKE` conditions looks backwards:

```
FROM DRUG1 D1 LEFT JOIN
     DRUG_LIST DL
      ON DL.O_DRUGS LIKE '%' || D1.GENERIC_NAME || '%'
```

Note:  Table aliases such as `a` are generally meaningless. Use abbreviations of the table names.